# How do I find the Google's OAuth 2.0 client-secret-key for developing chrome-extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I see only the following details in

https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/#project:xxxxx:access

**Client ID for installed applications**

- Client ID: 477522346600.apps.googleusercontent.com
- Application type: Chrome App
- Application ID: gobkdpbocikdfbnfahjladnetpdkvmic

**Simple API Access**

- API key: AIzaSyDC_BSfqa1Uhgh3M6KqYUvzXuKX0lMnMaw
- Referers: Any referer allowed
- Activated on: Mar 21, 2013 4:35 AM
- Activated by:  xxx@yyyy.com – you

Now, what's my client-secret value in the above data?

Answer (score 31):

OK, figured it out by myself.

- Click the **Download JSON** link in the **Client ID for installed applications** section.
- Open the JSON in a text-file.
- You will find the **client-secret**.

Comment: dude, thanks, came here with the same question and too was unable to find more convinient way to get secret id, now at least I have it:)

Comment: I am able to find client-secret when i downloaded the JSON, where did you find the API key? I am not able to see it in the URL you have given.

Comment: Hi Satya, i am also tried this. i did not get client secret key.(i had created client id using installed application android in google api console.) when i used to create other, that time only i will get client secret key.

Comment: Hi,I'm unable to find consumer secret in the json what is the key for the consumer key in the json?

Comment: @Seenu69 I think 'consumer secret' is an OAuth 1.0 term, and OAuth 1.0 is deprecated.

Comment: @satya, I had  created client id using chrome app and then I tried downloading that file but it is not having the client secret. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Seenu69 According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps), OAuth 2.0 requests a client secret. I am still unable to find it.

Comment: Found it! In my API Console, Google Auto generated an OAuth 2.0 entry with label `Web client (auto created by Google Service)`. The JSON of this entry brings the `client_secret` (what makes sense), required for the authentication.

Comment: The filename downloaded was named as client_secret_<client_id>. No clue where is client secret still

Comment: I believe that you can improve this answer :). For example, giving more details for each step, and some images, if you want to.

Answer (score 3):

On Credentials page, 
place cursor over Name (Name is not underlined without cursor over it)
once Name is highlighted and underlined, click.

[image: Credentials->cursor over name to highlight link, then click]

[image: Client Secret Screen will app]

Answer (score 2):

For credentials with `Chrome App` you won't get a `client_secret` only the `client_id`. I suggest creating it as type `other` instead. This should give you an ID and a secret you can use for your extension.

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone will step into thi misunderstanding like I did.

If you create OAuth client with Application type "android" (and Chrome App as @Erich answered) you won't get client secret.

Use this (picture) instructions to acquire the key.
[image]

Comment: i already had created the oath screen (it's pending verification) but can't find the secret anywhere, any hints?

Comment: @raiton Do you solved it? I follow instrutions above without success

Answer (score 0):

Download file JSON Client ID :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AckK.png)

File name JSON is Client secret :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Zav.png)

And client secret is same client ID

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).